# How to change Bar apexchart label

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I can't change Barchart label using of API data, here I have updated the series succesfully using

```
this.$refs.chart.updateSeries([{
          name: this.$t('totalGain'),
          data: this.obj.sortedvalues
}])
```

but I have tried everything for updating chart labels but Nothing works.

my code:

HTML:

```
<apexchart type="bar" ref="chart" :options="options" :series="series"></apexchart>
```

Script:

```
data: function () {
    return {
options: {
        stroke: {
          width: 7,
          curve: 'smooth'
        },
        chart: {
          type: 'bar',
          id: 'vuechart',
          height: 'auto',
          dropShadow: {
            enabled: true,
            enabledOnSeries: undefined,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            blur: 3,
            color: '#000',
            opacity: 0.35
          },
          colors: ['#F44336', '#E91E63', '#9C27B0'],
          plotOptions: {
            bar: {
              columnWidth: '45%',
              distributed: true
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [1, 2, 3]
        },
        title: {
          text: '',
          align: 'left',
          margin: 10,
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          floating: false,
          style: {
            fontSize: '14px',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontFamily: undefined,
            color: '#263238'
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'series-1',
        data: [15, 5, 7, 0, 8]
      }]
    }
```

Update Chart:

```
this.$refs.chart.updateSeries([{
          name: this.$t('totalGain'),
          data: this.obj.sortedvalues
}])
// here I need to change labels
```

I have tried acess directly to `categories` and patch option using updateOptions but didn't works!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know In VUEjs
But here is logic applied on reactjs

You need to pass key which hold the state variable counter in Chart component and You need to update chart series using state. Now and setting of state you need to update counter in key . Once your counter gets changed your whole component gets reRander and your label will gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

To update **both** the ***series*** and the ***labels***, you would simply provide the series and the labels together as an object and pass it to the chart's `updateOptions` method.

```
var updated_job_cat_chart_options = {
    series: job_categories_series,
    labels: job_categories_labels
};


myChart.updateOptions(updated_job_cat_chart_options);
```

**NB:** The job_categories_series is an array containing the series to be updated with and the job_categories_labels contains the labels.